# UITableViewCell background image path

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom background images for the cells. I have 4 images depending on where the cell is in the table. There's one for first row, middle rows, last row, and only row. I basically followed the tutorial here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

My issue occurs when a new cell is added to the table. The other cells don't update to reflect their new row positions.

When and how should I update these cells? ViewWillAppear? Or should I add it this method?

```
controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

Right now the background image assignment happens in a configureCell:atIndexPath function that I'm calling in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there aren't that many cells, you could simply call the reloadData method on the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, a more efficient approach would be to use something like the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method to only reload the rows you require. (You'll probably want to take a look at the [NSIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSIndexPath) reference to see how it maps to tables.)

Comment: How do I get the row before the row that was just updated.Since i'm using a fetchedResultsController I'm assuming I can place it in the insert case of this method: 

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:

Comment: It'll be "[indexPath row] - 1" if that makes sense.